# How to render data from Express into an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, frontend, backend

I've a simple `server.js` application. One route is the /api/showaccounts route. Its scope is to fetch from MongoDB a sequence of accounts (with username, balance and name fields):

```
app.post('/api/showaccounts', async (req, res) => {

        try {
            const response = await Account.find({})
            console.log(response)
            res.json({ status: "ok" })
    
        } catch (error) {
            res.json("Error")
            throw error
        }

})
```

When I do `console.log(response)` I see a JSON array:

```
[
  {
    username: 'bobo',
    balance: 245,
    name: 'bobo',
  }
]
```

Now, to the path `"./static/table.html"`:

```
<body>
  <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Username</th>
           <th>Balance</th>
           <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="data-output">
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

I simply want to add each JSON element of the previous array as row of this table. What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Need to install [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars)

Comment: Use [a template engine as described in the Express Guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Answer (score -2):

Here is a minimal example in plain JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/m3dx0eua/ You can try it out by clicking the `Run` button.

Note that

```
const response = [
  {
    username: 'bobo',
    balance: 245,
    name: 'bobo',
  },
    {
    username: 'alice',
    balance: 122,
    name: 'alice',
  },
      {
    username: 'bob',
    balance: 25,
    name: 'bob',
  }
];
```

is just an example, in reality you want to use your response object from your API.

## How it works

#### 1. Accessing the table

`const table = document.getElementById("data-output")` gets the table by its ID. We can now manipulate this HTML Element in JavaScript. [Learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

#### 2. iterating through the response

`response.forEach(dataset => appenDataSetToTable(table, dataset))` takes each first-level object (in our case dataset of each account) from `response` and calls the previously defined (that is important!) `appenDataSetToTable(table, dataset)` with the table element we got in step 1 and the current dataset. [Learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

#### 3. Building the table row

No we are in the `appendDataSetToTable` function. We have the table and the current dataset of our user "bobo". First, we need to create a new table row for bobo. We can do that by using `const tr = document.createElement('tr');`

In fact, we can create any HTML Tag dynamically by using `document.createElement(<HTML tag>)` [Learn moire here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

#### 4. Assigning the data

Now, we need to create `<td>`s for the individual data point. We do that in the same way as we created the table row before: `const tdUsername = document.createElement('td');`

We then need to assign data to the `<td>`. This is done by `tdUsername.innerText = dataset.username;`. `InnerText` is what is *in between* the opening and closing HTML tag. In this case, it translates to
`<td>bobo</td>`. [Learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

We repeat that for the balance and the name. In fact, we could use another function for that, sparing us of the manual work.

#### 5. Appending the child

When we are done with assigning the data to the `<td>`, we must assign the `<td>` to the `<tr>`. We can do that by calling `tr.appendChild(tdUsername);`

We repeat that for the balance and name, and finally we need to append the whole `<tr>` to the table: `table.appendChild(tr);`

[Learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

#### 6. Outlook

If that seems a little dull and fiddly, it is. Fortunately, there are tools to make your life much, much easier, even if they are initially harder to learn. A good choice for a beginner would be https://vuejs.org/. If you are interested, check it out.

Comment: The question is about doing this with **server-side** JavaScript built around Express.js.

Comment: @Quentin Last sentence of the original question: "I simply want to add each JSON element of the previous array as row of this table. What's the simplest way to do this?" Also, the title of the question is "How to render data from Express into an HTML table?" So no, I think not.

Comment: This seems to be the easyest way. Anyway I've one doubt:  const table = document.getElementById("data-output") -> ReferenceError: document is not defined. How do I refer to "./static/accounts.html"?